# Hex characters not rendering after upgrading from Ember 1.7 to Ember/CLI 2.6

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, mathquill

Does anyone have any insight into what might be different in Ember/Ember CLI, compared to a Rails delivered global app, to not render hex characters correctly?

I have/had an Ember 1.7 app that I build a Math Editor in. I render very simple buttons with hex chars like ∛ (`<div>&#x221b;</div>`) but in the new CLI app it gets escaped.

Im just curious if there is a setting or something that I missing in the way CLI handles templates that may be causing this issue.

UPDATE
I have static chars in the template itself. In some cases I have data that gets returned from the server (previous user input) and I have user generated chars that are input when using the editor.

Comment: You render? Does it mean you do it programatically (appending HTML via JavaScript, or having Ember variable that stores HTML) or in template (.hbs)?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear, but in my case, it happens with all 3 situations. 

I have static chars in the template itself. In some cases I have data that gets returned from the server (previous user input) and I have user generated chars that are input when using the editor.

Comment: You could use {{{variableThatHasSpecialCharacters}}} in template to stop Ember from escaping your special characters.